# How to save a video file from collection of images?

Tags: vb.net, video, save

I have a folder with 18 .png files, each 800x600px. I've created a List of Bitmaps and loaded each bitmap from file, storing them as Bitmaps in the list.

I'd like to know how to write a video file (for example, .AVI) in VB .NET using the collection of images. Specifically, I'm not just looking to simply put the images together — I'd like to have the option to loop through the collection of images multiple times, adding each Bitmap as a new frame to the end of the video. This would enable me to create a 60-minute long video of the same 18 frames repeating if I wanted to.

I'd need to be able to specify the framerate, and I won't be including audio.

To put this in context, I'm effectively creating an animated image for my digital photo frame. It can't animate the GIFs it displays, but it is capable of playing videos. The 18 frames are very similar to each other.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aforgenet.com/
The AForge Library has quite an extensive toolset for all sorts of video and image processing tasks.

Or you could use FFMPEG as a standalone tool. There you can combine images to a video:

[ffmpeg Video from Images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)